# Looping over array of objects, and summing up the values inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Given the following array:

```
const array = [
{
    date: '2016-12-13T00:00:00.000Z',
    stats: [
      {
        name: 'Soft Drinks',
        sold: 34,
      },
      {
        name: 'Snacks',
        sold: 3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Coffee and warm drinks',
        sold: 26,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    date: '2016-12-14T00:00:00.000Z',
    stats: [
      {
        name: 'Soft Drinks',
        sold: 34,
      },
      {
        name: 'Snacks',
        sold: 3,
      },
      {
        name: 'Coffee and warm drinks',
        sold: 26,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I would like to sum the sold values within the stats array.
the final array should look like:

```
const array = [
  stats: [
    {
      name: 'Soft Drinks',
      sold: 68,
    },
    {
      name: 'Snacks',
      sold: 6,
    },
    {
      name: 'Coffee and warm drinks',
      sold: 52,
    },
  ],
]
```

So basically like initiate over the array dates, sum up the stats of every day, If the name match then += the value.

I did so far:

```
const result = {};
array.forEach(

(item) => {
    const { stats } = item;
    stats.forEach((item) => {
      Object
        .keys(item)
        .forEach((value) => {
          result[value] = (result[value] || 0) + item[value];
      });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

But I'm kinda lost at the second loop. What is the proper way to achieve the result?

Comment: Your example "final" `array` is invalid, which makes it virtually impossible to make out what you really want to do. Could you update that?

Comment: @Daenu: Better yet, a runnable example here on-site instead of off on another site, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True! Forgot that

Comment: The error is in the `Object.keys` loop: you need to code the logic that says that the key is the `item.name`, and the sum is the `item.sold`. So: `stats.forEach((item) => { result[item.name] = (result[item.name] || 0) + item.sold });` Your current code combines all the keys, including the name.